# Best way to debug MySQL slow queries?

Tags: linux, mysql

First of all I like to inform you that I am a new User on Linux administration and I need some help.

I own a CloudLinux web server, and I am faced with a MySQL Slow Queries problem. The problem is that I have several users on my host, that run lot's of slow queries, and this has as a result the MySQL Service termination (I suppose that is termination. In reality, the MySQL server does not respond at all).

The question now is, how can I debug this queries ? I know about the slow queries log file. Already I have see the file, but the content is too hard to get read it. So is there any better way used by Pro ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Percona query digest tool to build summaries of the slow query log. This will help you find the slowest of the slow:

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html

Then use mysql's EXPLAIN command to figure out WHY a particular query is slow:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble understanding the slow queries log file, then you would probably bestto buy professional DBA services to help you resolve the issue.

Generally, a query runs slow if it ties up a lot of resources and there is resource contention on the server, namely CPU, memory and I/O.

Apart from buying a bigger, faster server, indexing tables relevant to your slow queries could be one way to help improve performance.  Check out this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29582/enabling-log-queries-not-using-indexes-disables-long-query-time).

You can also enable query caching to help offload the need to repeat really expensive queries.

Anyway, this is just for a start.

-- ab1

Answer (score 1):

EXPLAIN is the most basic way to get information about how the query performs. It is supported by all MySQL versions. Most important you will see how indexes are used.

I use SQLyog for this.